# Can you dodge or is there a dodge check?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat

Is there a way to dodge an attack?

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail about what's going on for you? What research have you done and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4):

First off, bear in mind that your ability to 'dodge' is part of your Armor Class and your Reflex Save. 'Dodging' is already part of what your character is try to do in order to evade damage.

Armor Class

> Some characters have a high AC because they are extremely quick or intelligent and **able to dodge well**, while other characters have a high AC because they wear heavy protective armor that is difficult to penetrate.

Reflex Save

> Reflex measures your ability to predict attacks or to deflect **or dodge** an attack. It’s useful against areas of effect such as dragon breath or a 
>   fireball spell.

(PBH 274. Emphasis Mine)

But if you want to take things even further...

One of your options for a Standard Action in Combat is 'Total Defense.' This is the closest thing 4E has to a 'Dodge' action. Your character uses their Standard Action to focus entirely on defending themselves, and gains a +2 bonus to all defenses (AC, Reflex, Will, and Fortitude).

> TOTAL DEFENSE: STANDARD ACTION
>   ✦
>   +2 Bonus to All Defenses: You gain a +2 bonus to all defenses until the start of your next turn.

(PHB 292)

Comment: This answer would be improved by references, but is otherwise entirely correct: Characters *always* try to dodge.